# How to reset root password on a Linux VM on Windows Azure?

Tags: linux, ssh, azure

I have a Linux VM running for over a year on Azure. I have forgotten the  password to my account. I am however still able to ssh into the vm as it has my ssh key. Note that the root account does not have my ssh key, so I can't ssh into root. Also I can't sudo once I ssh as it prompts for password.

I tried using azure cli, specifically http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/08/25/using-vmaccess-extension-to-reset-login-credentials-for-linux-vm/ . This does not work for as my waagent version is WALinuxAgent-1.3.2 and the minimum need is 2+.

Is there any other way I can reset the root password on this vm ?

Comment: You can't use `sudo`?

Comment: No, I am unable to use sudo as it prompts for password

Comment: And you forgot your own password, also?

Comment: I just edited the question, there is no root password. The user account is in sudoers, so I could `sudo su` from it. However now I can't as it prompts for password and I don't remember it

Answer (score 9):

I don't know much about Azure but I'd assume you can change the password with administrator access. 
In linux:

```
sudo passwd root
```

In windows:

(in administrator cmd)

```
net users root *
```

Answer (score 3):

This particular issue is probably solved by now (hopefully).  If you cannot login to your remote access account, I recommend Azure CLI over powershell.  The steps actual work, and are far easier.

Note: This example is tested with the new Resource Manager type VMs.

Make sure azure cli is installed.
open a terminal

```
$ azure login
```

Note: follow instructions to enter the temporary access code into a browser

Check your active subscription:

```
$ azure account list
```

If its not already, set the subscription you need.  You can verify its id in the azure portal by accessing the subscriptions resource

```
$ azure account set <SubName or SubId>
```

Set Resource Manager mode

```
$ azure config mode arm
```

Reset Password.  This command will install the extension required also.  It takes a while, so grab a drink!

```
$ azure vm reset-access -g <res-group-name> -n <vm-name> -u <username> -p <new-pwd>
```

Comment: 2021, may need updating for az cli, see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/vmaccess

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any information to help in your specific scenario but a workaround would be downloading the disk and creating a vm on a local hyper-v using this disk. That way you will have console access and the possibility to enter recovery mode to reset the password. Next, upload the vhd back and redeploy the VM.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have azure specific experience, however if you can get console access you could boot the VM into single user mode and reset the password from there.

Answer (score 0):

Nick's answer updated for azure CLI 2.0:

Login:

```
az login
```

Set Account:

```
az account set -s <accountname>
```

Reset Password:

```
az vm user update --resource-group <res-group-name> --name <vmname> --username <username> --password <newpassword>
```